# show that $\mathbb{Z}_p^2/p\mathbb{Z}_p^2 \cong (\mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p )^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and its ring of integer $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then show that $\mathbb{Z}_p^2/p\mathbb{Z}_p^2 \cong \left(\mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p \right)^2$, where $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ has a ring structure.

**Answer:**

To show there is an isomorphism, let us consider the natural homomorphism $\pi :\mathbb{Z}_p^2 \to \left(\mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p \right)^2 ,$ defined by $$\pi (r^2)=(r+p \mathbb{Z}_p)^2. $$

I think it is subjective homorphism. Now we have to show $kernel=p\mathbb{Z}_p^2$.

Help me at this position.

You can suggest me other methods also

Comment: Let's start by making sense of $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$.  What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: So why are you writing $r^2$ in $\pi(r^2)=(r+p\mathbb{Z}_p)^2$?

Comment: @user10354138, ok I might be wrong defining this. You correct the function please and prove the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can consider the natural map $f \colon \mathbb{Z}_p^2 \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$ given by sending a tuple $(a,b)$ to $(a + p\mathbb{Z}_p, b + p\mathbb{Z}_p)$ as you tried yourself. Now the kernel is given by all tuples $(c,d)$ such that $p$ is a divisor of $c$ and $d$. In other words we have $\text{ker}(f) = (p\mathbb{Z}_p)^2$.

Edit:
The set $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ is (at least usually) not the set of squares in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but the product of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. This means we have $\mathbb{Z}_p^2 = \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p = \lbrace (a,b) \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_p \rbrace$ and likewise for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: how did you get the tuple $(a,b)$ in the domain ?

Comment: Let me edit my answer to clarify some things.

Comment: nice answer sir